# MYSQL ORDER BY CASE stored value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Im trying to show first the value that is stored in the 'zone' field, since each customer has different value, I want the one in his ZONE to show first in his lists. Thanks

first run a query for using the VAR later

```
$data = "SELECT * FROM users;
$datas = mysqli_query($con,$data) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$query = mysqli_fetch_array($datas);
```

Now I can use the {$query['zone']} and show those first in the query

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE  ORDER by zone CASE zone WHEN '{$query['zone']}' THEN 0 ELSE 2'";
```

Im not getting the expected results, any advice?  Thanks

Comment: You're missing the condition after `WHERE`.

Comment: Can you provide a test data and desired result?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
ORDER by (zone = '{$query['zone']}') desc,
         zone
```

This assumes that the expression `'{$query['zone']}'` is the zone that you want to give priority to.  User's whose zone's match this will appear first.

Comment: @GuchoCa . . . That should have been `zone`.